# Why doesn't this JavaScript highlight button code work?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am not sure why this code does not work. What I am trying to achieve is I would like to click the button and highlight some text.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>the title</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="/jquery/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#button").click(function(){
         $(".target").effect( "highlight", 
          {color:"#ffff00"}, 30000 );
      });

   });
   </script>
  
</head>
<body>

   <button id="button">Take Hint</button>

   <p><span class="target">this text needs to highlight
   </span></p>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi have you checked if the effect api is included on your jquery custom script

Comment: make sure the script path are correct.  the code is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/x3e65vrf/

Comment: I got the code from this site and altered it a bit: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/effect-highlight.htm

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. It works on the site but when I add this to my html page and test, it doesn't work.

Comment: how many js do you have maybe it has a conflict. try to look on your console for error.

Comment: There are 2 js: <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>

Comment: got it to work needed and additional jquery code to make it work.